# Samba, winbindd and multiple home directories

Tags: samba, passwd, winbind

My current situation is a system with an Windows AD and DC, which manage logging in to Samba. After an Upgrade of the underlieing OS from Windows Server 2008R2 to 2016, my coinfig doesn't work anymore.
I try to setup samba with the home directories of the respective user.
Now I have got 3 home dirs, /home1, /home2 and /home3, where merging is impossible.
How can I get winbindd to use the home-directory of a user that is given in /etc/passwd?
I can't change big things in the system as it's production.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: 
The home-directories are not used, because winbindd does something like "\", so it doesn't find all my users and their respective home directories.

Comment: `winbindd` _does_ use a user's home directory given in `/etc/passwd` where one exists. If your configuration doesn't then you're going to need to provide more information (for example, the non-comment lines from your `[global]` section in `smb.conf`).